# Volume of boundary of Alexandrov space.

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional compact Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below which has non-empty boundary. Is it true that the boundary has Hausdorff dimension $n-1$? If yes, does it have finite positive $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure?

A reference would be helpful.